# celery doesn't find python-dateutil, although it is installed

Tags: python, virtualenv, celery

I have a virtualenv activated and I am running a command

```
 celery -A dnslookup worker --loglevel=info
```

throws

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/myuser/dev/project-backend-ENV/bin/celery", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/Users/myuser/dev/project-backend-ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-   0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2607, in <module>
File "/Users/myuser/dev/project-backend-ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: python-dateutil>=1.5,<2.0
```

but python-dateutil is installed in my virtualenv.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are using a version of `dateutil` which is too new. Installing `dateutil` to a fresh virtualenv gets me `dateutil` version 2.1 by default, which is not going to work (as your error message points out). From the [Celery changelog](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/2.2/changelog.html):

> Dependency lists now explicitly specifies that we don’t want
>   python-dateutil 2.x, as this version only supports py3k.
>
> If you have installed dateutil 2.0 by accident you should downgrade to the
>   1.5.0 version:
>
> ```
> pip install -U python-dateutil==1.5.0
> ```

Comment: you are absolutely right. this solves it - thank you.
however, is the default dateutil 2.0 when my python version is 2.7 - this doesn't make much sense?

Comment: @flavio87 - I agree, this seems broken behaviour on the part of dateutil. Their [website](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) says *Ported to Python 3, by Brian Jones. If you need dateutil for Python 2.X, please continue using the 1.X series.*

Comment: There's a new dateutil version (2.1) that works on both Python 2 and 3.  Sadly it doesn't support Python 2.5, and Celery will not drop 2.5 support until celery 3.1 (and then we can update the dateutil dependency).  It could be that your system had dateutil 2.1 installed when this happened